# Android: Dialog Interaction

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create a custom spinner.I could show the dialog including the list view,when a button is cliked. But my problem is that I want interaction to both Dialog and the views behind it at the same time. ie I should be able to select one item from the list view in the Dialog and also I should be able to click that button again.Is that possible.Pls help

Comment: I don't think that is possible, since your button and dialog are in two different views.

Comment: It is possible using FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL

Answer (score 0):

I could do that using LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;